ksqldb explode multiple list elements
I have data like this:
One Kafka Message:
[{"source": "858256_6052+571", "numericValue": null, "created": 1725969039288, "textValue": "mytestData"}]
Another Kafka Message:
[{"source": "858256_6052+571", "numericValue": null, "created": 1725969039288, "textValue": "mytestData2"}, {"source": "858256_6052+571", "numericValue": null, "created": 1725969039288, "textValue": "mytestData3"}]
I want ksql to create a stream of three elements for this. How can i do this? I already tried it with explode but there i need a key that i do not have in my data.
My current query attempt:
CREATE STREAM ml_stream_raw (
    data ARRAY<STRUCT<source VARCHAR, numericValue DOUBLE, created BIGINT, textValue VARCHAR>>
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='testml1withlist',
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON'
);

CREATE STREAM ml_stream_raw_exploded AS
    SELECT EXPLODE(data) AS message
    FROM ml_stream_raw;

CREATE STREAM ml_stream_raw_processed AS
    SELECT 
        message->source AS source,
        message->numericValue AS numericValue,
        message->created AS created,
        message->textValue AS textValue
    FROM  ml_stream_raw_exploded;

CREATE TABLE ml_table_messages_per_second_list AS
    SELECT 'all_messages' AS message_group,
           WINDOWSTART AS window_start,
           COUNT(*) AS message_count
    FROM ml_stream_raw_processed
    WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 SECOND)
    GROUP BY 'all_messages';

SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(window_start, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS window_start_formatted,
       message_count
FROM ml_table_messages_per_second_list
EMIT CHANGES;


Can you also show us your current query attempt?

@jarlh oh sorry, i added it :)
